# Entity Framework - Object Properties

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework for my model/data access, and running into speed issues, hopefully someone can assist?

What I've been doing is using the EF diagram with the default code generator to generate partial classes describing anything that is going to be persisted. I then have partial classes with methods and non-persisted properties. These might be simple things like full name as the concatenated first/last names, or derived from related entities, such as total stock as the sum of the collection of stock locations' quantity.

Any methods accessing related entities do work, but seem to be very slow. Here's an example of an especially slow one, it takes about 6-7 seconds:

Quick description of entities involved:

Supplier --> supplies many SupplierLines, each has cost price
SupplierLine --> broken down into StockLines
StockLine --> has many Locations, each location has quantity

So I'm trying to add a method to get the total stock value from a supplier, i.e. mySupplier.StockValue() which should obviously be the total of cost price x total quantity for each supplier line and its stock lines.

I've done this as a function in Supplier as:

```
Public Function StockValue() As Decimal
        Return SupplierLines.
            Sum(Function(sul) sul.LastPrice * sul.StockLines.Sum(Function(skl) skl.Locations.Sum(Function(l) l.Quantity)))
    End Function
```

Which gives correct results, but takes forever to do so.

Any thoughts as to how I can get better results?

- I want to keep my model classes persistence-ignorant
- I want to keep all my logic compile-checked
- I want to everything to be easily unit-testable using fake data sources
- I don't really want to pre-load this information, because it isn't always needed

Comment: Did you try to use a profiler to see what query entity framework is executing on the SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an Include()... method that extends IEnumerable, and use that. It resolves the performance issues, while maintaining ignorance of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most probably lazy loading. If you load only `Supplier` entity it doesn't load its realted `SupplierLine` instances and they related `StockLine` instances and their related `Location` instances. If this is really case (if you didn't `Include` them in query retrieving `Supplier`) the situation is as follows:

1. `SupplierLines.` - executes query to database to get all lines for current Supplier
2. `sul.StockLines.` - executes separate query for **each** supplier line to get its stock lines
3. `skl.Locations.` - executes separate query for **each** stock line to get its locations

So depending on amount of data you have in these collections you can end up with tens to thousands sql queries executed in your first call to `StockValue`. Next call will be fast because data are already loaded.

If you want to avoid it you must retrieve supplier with all its realted data:

```
context.Supplier.Include("SupplierLines.StockLines.Locations").Where(...);
```

Comment: I feared as much... trouble with that is that the supplier's methods now depend on the context... and on the hard-coded string

Comment: No supplier doesn't depend on context (not directly). The code above should represent object set exposed on context instance (not directly Supplier). Hardcoded string can be problem if you want to refactor names of your navigatio properties. There is strongly typed alternative but you must use EF 4.1 RC.

Comment: Ah, so do you mean that the thing that is getting the supplier from the context (i.e. controller) should do the Include? I suppose that's almost fair enough in that the controller depends on the context anyway, and knows that it wants to access that property. Feels messy though. I'm using a repository pattern to access my data, so suppose that also means I need to expose the Include method or similar.